# Javascript Show/Hide elements, why isn't this code working?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, show-hide

So, as you can see I amusing javascript to show/hide elements, however when you click the .png it shows the text but does not hide the other element's text.  I have been going over and over this script and Google searching the hell out of it and I cannot come up with an answer.  I think I need another pair of eyes, so if anyone takes a look at this let me know if there are errors or if I'm missing some code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="NKit.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
function hideStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}

</script>

</head> 

<body> 

<div class="content">

<section class="left">  

        <p>
            <a href="#" onclick="showStuff('character1');" onclick="hideStuff('character2');"><img src="character1.png" id="char1" /></a>

        </p> 

        <p>
            <a href="#" onclick="showStuff('character2');" onclick="hideStuff('character1');"><img src="character2.png" id="char2" /></a>
        </p> 

</section>

<section class="right">

        <span id="character1" style="display: none;">Show character1 information</span> 

        <span id="character2" style="display: none;">Character 2 information</span> 

</section>

</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why are there tow times "onClick" in each anchor?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="showStuff('character1');" onclick="hideStuff('character2');">
```

On this line, you first set the property `onclick` to `showStuff('character1')`, then you **reassign** it to `hideStuff('character2')`.

So, you should wrap these two function calls into one function and then assign that function to `onclick`.

```
onclick="function() { showStuff('character1'); hideStuff('character2'); }
```